# jquery gallery with banner ads

Tags: jquery, gallery, slideshow

Does anyone know if there's a JQuery gallery plugin that supports banner ads? I've seen a lot of many different slideshow/gallery options out there but I'm looking for one that will enable me to have a banner load with each photo.

I see that this NBC site is running something like that ([example here](http://www.nbclosangeles.com/entertainment/music/NATLRock-Stars-Then-and-Now-97329329.html)), but I can't find a plugin.

Comment: see [piccante](http://www.piccante.co)

Comment: I didn't see any galleries there that allowed for the images and an ad.

Comment: http://www.piccante.co/?pg=galleriesimages

Comment: yes, I saw that page, I meant I didn't see any galleries there that allowed the user to display a photograph along with a banner ad and other sidebar info like the example I linked to.